# How to perform calculation using custom function and display result using Php

Tags: wordpress

I want to perform calculation in my wordpress website.Right now i am putting static data.Please help me out to how to perform calculation so that i can get dynamic result

Comment: What kind of calculation? Have you tried writing this function yet? Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Your questoin is too ambiguous. You will need profile provide proper details of exactly what functionality you are trying to implement.

Comment: i want to submit a input from one page and display the result in next page by multiplying that input with different cost .

Comment: How to perform this in wordpress to show result in other page on clicking submit button